# React Native Debugger uses wrong version of react-devtools

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-devtools, react-native-debugger

Trying to debug apps with React Native Debugger. Shows "Unsupported DevTools backend version".

[image]

**How I got here**

I created a new app using `expo init` (expo-cli@5.2.0) with **TypeScript blank template**.
Started app with `expo ios`, opened 'Debug Remote JS'

**I have tried:**

1. `yarn global add react-devtools@^4.22.0`
2. Change package.json to include:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-devtools": "^4.22.0",
    "react-devtools-core": "^4.22.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
},
"resolutions": {
    "react-devtools-core": "4.22.0"
  }
```

```
Deleted yarn.lock and /node_modules, then ran `yarn install`
```

3. Reinstall React Native Debugger

I also get this error when Debugger connects to the app:
(after I dismiss this error, I get the one presented above ^)

[image]

**P.S.:**
I can provide any additional information. I have been struggling with this for a few days now

Comment: Hi, can you tell your steps to resolve this issue? I am getting the same issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is being generated because the version of `react-devtools` of the project and that of `react-devtools-core` are not compatible each other.
So you should look at both versions and upgrade one's or downgrade another one's. I hope it helps.